# Renaming a variable in a string format

Tags: java

One functionality of smart IDE's is renaming variable. As an example in Eclipse when you select a variable and hit alt+shift+r then you can rename all of its occurrences in current block.

Write a function that is given a function source code, and a variable name in it. Then rename the given variable to new name given. But when i replace the variables for example

```
 String str = "void aMethod(int a, int b) {     System.out.println(a + b); }" 

    static void j3wRenameVariable(String sourceCode, String var2Rename, String newName) {

      StringBuffer source = new StringBuffer(sourceCode);
        char var2 = var2Rename.charAt(0);
        String a="";

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            if(source.charAt(i) == var2){
             a = source.replace(i, i + var2Rename.length(), newName).toString();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);


}
```

this program change the function name a swill.

Comment: i am failing to recognize a question. Can you elaborate on what you're asking, specifically?

Comment: well you just compare the `chars`, you don´t care or check if it´s relevant.

Comment: Can you include the example variable name and output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to isolate your variable. How about a reg-ex?

```
return source.replaceAll("(\\W)(" + var2Rename + ")(\\W)", "$1" + newName + "$3");
```

Explanation. The `\\W` will check for non-letter characters, eg the boundary of a variable expression. We want a boundary on both sides of the variable, and then to replace we need to make sure the matched boundary characters are included hence the "$1", and "$3".